# You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, authorization

when url used like this "domainname.ddns.info/projectname" it works and web becomes accessible but when url used like this "domainname.ddns.info" it popup error saying 'Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials'. Users always use domain name to brows the site not full url, where is the error here and how to solve it ?

Comment: Check the security settings at the root level and at the folder level and see if there is a difference.  P.S. you've tagged the question both asp.net and asp-classic.  Are you running both?

Comment: sorry, i am running asp.net only.